# IndexError: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. Use tensor.item() to convert a 0-dim tensor to a Python number

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

```
def nms(bboxes,scores,threshold=0.5):
    '''
    bboxes(tensor) [N,4]
    scores(tensor) [N,]
    '''
    x1 = bboxes[:,0]
    y1 = bboxes[:,1]
    x2 = bboxes[:,2]
    y2 = bboxes[:,3]
    areas = (x2-x1) * (y2-y1)

    _,order = scores.sort(0,descending=True)
    keep = []
    while order.numel() > 0:
        i = order[0]
        keep.append(i)

        if order.numel() == 1:
            break

        xx1 = x1[order[1:]].clamp(min=x1[i])
        yy1 = y1[order[1:]].clamp(min=y1[i])
        xx2 = x2[order[1:]].clamp(max=x2[i])
        yy2 = y2[order[1:]].clamp(max=y2[i])

        w = (xx2-xx1).clamp(min=0)
        h = (yy2-yy1).clamp(min=0)
        inter = w*h

        ovr = inter / (areas[i] + areas[order[1:]] - inter)
        ids = (ovr<=threshold).nonzero().squeeze()
        if ids.numel() == 0:
            break
        order = order[ids+1]
    return torch.LongTensor(keep)
```

I tried

```
i=order.item()
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 24):

I found the solution in the github issues [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/flownet2-pytorch/issues/113#issuecomment-450802359)

Try to change

```
i = order[0] # works for PyTorch 0.4.1.
```

to

```
i = order # works for PyTorch>=0.5.
```

Answer (score 11):

I was trying to run a standard Convolutional Neural Network(LeNet) on MNIST using PyTorch. I was getting this error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last

 79         y = net.forward(train_x, dropout_value)
 80         loss = net.loss(y,train_y,l2_regularization)
 81         loss_train = loss.data[0]
 82         loss_train += loss_val.data

 IndexError: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. Use tensor.item() to convert a 
 0-dim tensor to a Python number
```

**Changing**

```
loss_train = loss.data[0]
```

**To**

```
loss_train = loss.data
```

**fixed the problem.**

Comment: This answer looks like a question and answer that doesn't match the original questions.  You should probably ask a new question and, if you're providing an answer yourself, add the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the loop body as:

```
while order.numel() > 0:
        if order.numel() == 1:
            break
        i = order[0]
        keep.append(i)
```

The code `i = order[0]` gives error when there is only one element left in `order`.